# iOS native-layer automation

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, automation, lte

I need to automate iPhones (6s) that are in a radiated screen room to place VoLTE calls to each other. I have already done this with Android, I set a laptop in the screen room and connect the Android phones via USB and then run scripts from the command line using ADB which automates the native-layer on the phones. I need similar capability for iPhones. Apple says no solution exists. I have looked into other software (Ranorex, TestPlant, Conflair, etc.) but they cannot meet my needs as they are unable to access or automate the native-layer, only the application-layer. But I am not trying to automate an app, I need to automate the phones.

I would prefer not to jail break, and my iPhones need to be running the latest iOS version. So, is it possible? How can I get equivalent functionality of ADB for iOS?

Comment: I am not asking what is recommended or opinion but what is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple does not expose the ability to place phone calls to third party apps. They specifically block all such access from third party apps. You would need to build a rig that operated the screen like a user, which would not be easy or very reliable.

Comment: I am not trying to call a third party app, just normal phone calls, the iPhone 6s is VoLTE capable so as long as the network has VoLTE capability, then it is just a normal phone call using the native phone app. Does that change anything?

Comment: and do you know why my question would be down voted? Is it a bad question, asked badly, asked in the wrong forum?

Comment: Some people just like down voting, you asked a very valid point

Comment: Dunno. It wasn't me doing the down voting. It is more of a test automation question than a strictly programming question, but still seems legit to me.

Comment: There are a lot of "driveby down-voters" here on SO. It's maddening. I don't mind if somebody doesn't like my question or answer and decides it deserves a down-vote, but in that case post a comment explaining your objections!

Comment: Looks like robotics is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, although you will need to use radio-transparent robotics if you don't want to alter your results.

Comment: @JParks, Somebody else pointed out that you might be able to use Siri and a bluetooth headset. Recorded "Siri, call 415-555-1212" commands would be a helluva lot easier than building a phone dialing robot.

Comment: True, I could pre-record it so it can all be in the screen room. Otherwise, nothing gets in or out of the screen room. It is kinda air-gaped.

Comment: Faraday cage, huh? Would a bluetooth transmitter interfere with your tests, being an RF transmitter?

Comment: Siri should also work with a wired headset.  If you are testing VoLTE, you should already have automated audio play and record capability.

Comment: I will try the pre-recorded Siri wired headset method first, I need to be careful not to add RF interference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this externally, not over USB or via software.  Possible external mechanisms might include a robotically controlled touch stylus and an emulated audio headset.  If needed to avoid RF interference, you may need to find/build an pneumatically actuated robotic interface for the touch stylus.

Added: Another possibility: It may be possible to set it up (in the Settings app) so that Siri via Bluetooth or wired-headset audio can place a phone call.

An emulated wired-headset with a prerecorded message and "Hey Siri" enabled in Settings might work.  Also disable Auto-Lock in Settings.

Comment: For security reasons, phone calls require external-to-the-device user interaction.

Comment: Hmmm that is a good idea, except I have no network drop into the screen room, nothing gets in and nothing gets out. I have an entire research LTE network in there with no access to the outside world.

Comment: Your current setup uses USB in the screen room?  That should work for robotics and audio as well.

Comment: Yup, looks like robotics is the answer. Kind of crazy, but I still love Apple.

Comment: Well time to get those raspberry pi to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Like what duncan said, it is not possible with ios. I sometimes miss androids 'freedom' when i code in ios, at the same time as an end user happy that ios is 'strict' about this kind of stuff

Comment: I agree! But the freedom in Android can be a double edged sword.